# Java and thermal receipt printer

Tags: java, printing

Does anyone know how to print receipt use Java?
I have googled for a long time. It seems Java POS should be a good solution. I have a quick look at it and it looks need the printer's Java driver. My printer is a cheap one, support ESC, but only have Windows driver.

I also tried:

```
 FileWriter out = new FileWriter("LPT1");
```

It does not work,

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: lpt1
>   (The system cannot find the file
>   specified)

Printable does not work neither.

Does any one know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: LPT1 isn't a file... it's a port.  Which is why *File*Writer doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the [Java Print Service API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jps/index.html) of use ? If not, perhaps the [javacomm](http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/) package since you're writing to a serial port.

Comment: Can you print to the printer normally, outside of a Java program?  Does it show up as a printer from the OS?

Comment: See my comment re. javacomm above. Perhaps this is of use.

Comment: I think Thermal Receipt Printer is different from the printers we use everyday. The printer was installed successfully in Windows 7. But the print test cannot perform successfully:( 
I tried java comm, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax is as follows:

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter("LPT1:");
```

There was a colon missing.

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen to be an IP Printer? If so, they generally listen on port 9100, and you can just write to that directly (text data) and it will print. You'll want to look up appropriate escape sequences, to do various things (cut, for example).

Comment: no, I connect it directly to my pc. I checked the printer, the port is LTP1:(

Comment: Can you please help me to know what should I make sure to buy a thermal printer that can be integrated with my java software? I mean either I can connect every printer with my Java code, or is there some specfics?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle these things is via JavaPOS APIs; but even then, you can still get stuck when the Maker of your hardware does not provide the appropriate drivers, in which case you are stuck at serial ports. Give JavaPOS a look, it might make your work very easy.

[JavaPos Website](http://www.javapos.com)

Comment: Could you update the link to JavaPos website to the relevant part instead of the homepag?